Having picture of Mokshed father with gods idol in temple wrong?
Is it sin or be cursed if you put pictures of your dead father in mandir and pray along with other gods ?

Praying at own home more appropriate as he may not be known to all in the past.

It’s at my home mandir, I am getting comments like , should not put father’s picture with gods in even home mandir

You are master of your own house. I would quickly distance myself from those who cannot go with my dharmic sentiments.
